# SyntaxError: unexpected token: '+='

Tags: javascript, loop

I'm looping through records and setting a variable according to an if statement. I'm trying to build the output variable with the results of all the looped records into one string using +=. I'm getting the syntax error referenced in the title of this thread. Not sure how to fix this or if I'm even using the right statement. See code below.

```
 function getEquipment() {
        dfd = $.Deferred();
            var id, hardWare, currentQty, newQty, minusCalc, strMessage;
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("SD-WAN Equipment");
            var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
            caml.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="LinkID" /><Value Type="Lookup">' + parentId + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
            listItems = list.getItems(caml);
            context.load(listItems, "Include(ID, Hardware_x0020_Model, New, Current)");
            context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                var count = listItems.get_count();
                var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
                while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                    listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
                    id = listItem.get_item("ID");
                    hardWare = listItem.get_item('Hardware_x0020_Model');
                    newQty = listItem.get_item('New');
                    currentQty = listItem.get_item('Current');
                    minusCalc = newQty - currentQty;
                    var diff = function (newQty, currentQty) { return Math.abs(newQty - currentQty);}
                    if (minusCalc > 0) {
                        strMessage = "Shipped: " + hardWare + " (" + diff(newQty,currentQty) +") \n";
                    } else if (minusCalc < 0) {
                        strMessage = "Reclaimed: " + hardWare + " (" + diff(newQty,currentQty) +") \n";
                    }
                    var strFinal += strMessage;  <==== ERROR HERE
                } // End while
                dfd.resolve();
            }, function() {
                dfd.reject();
            });
            return dfd.promise();
    } //End getEquipment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accumulate the results of your loop, you should declare a variable outside of it and then use inside the loop:

```
 var strFinal = '';
 while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    ....
    strFinal += strMessage;
} // End while
```

Comment: This is the answer, you can't attach some value to a newly created variable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're re-declaring the variable. I can't recall with Javascript but normally you can't use the `+=` assignment statement when also declaring the variable. Try this for your onSuccess function:

```
function() {
    var count = listItems.get_count();
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    var strFinal='';
    while ( listEnumerator.moveNext() ) {
        listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        id = listItem.get_item( "ID" );
        hardWare = listItem.get_item( 'Hardware_x0020_Model' );
        newQty = listItem.get_item( 'New' );
        currentQty = listItem.get_item( 'Current' );
        minusCalc = newQty - currentQty;
        var diff = function( newQty, currentQty ) {
            return Math.abs( newQty - currentQty );
        }
        if ( minusCalc > 0 ) {
            strMessage = "Shipped: " + hardWare + " (" + diff( newQty, currentQty ) + ") \n";
        } else if ( minusCalc < 0 ) {
            strMessage = "Reclaimed: " + hardWare + " (" + diff( newQty, currentQty ) + ") \n";
        }
        strFinal += strMessage; // <= === ERROR HERE
    } // End while
    dfd.resolve();
}
```

Where you declare the `var strFinal;` outside the While loop, rather than declaring it with the assignment operator like you had (ie `var strFinal = strMessage`)

Answer (score 0):

Why syntax error? Because you try to concatenate value to undeclared variable.

Try this is your browser:

```
var a = 'abc';
var b += a;
```

It will give you same error.

Your variable strFinal not declared before += operator. += require to variable be declared before operation.